# Is a matrix group with a continuum of generators always a Lie group?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups

Suppose that you have a set of matrices $S \subseteq SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, and furthermore you know that $S$ contains a continuum of matrices. (In particular, assume that there is some one-parameter family of elements $s_t \in S$, which vary continuously over some nontrivial subset of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ as $t$ ranges over $[0,1]$.)

Let $\langle S \rangle$ be the set of matrices generated by finite products of elements of $S$ and their inverses. Is $G$ necessarily a Lie group?

Clearly $\langle S \rangle$ is a group, and furthermore the closure of $\langle S \rangle$ in $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a Lie group by the closed subgroup theorem. The question I'm asking is: if you already know there is a continuum of operations in your generating set, does this guarantee that the resulting matrix group generated is a Lie group, even if it's not closed in $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: For background, I'm interested in this for an application in quantum computing. In particular, I want to ensure that $\langle S \rangle$ is a Lie group, and hence the tangent space to the curves $s_t$ at the identity are in the Lie algebra of the group.

Comment: Usually the notation $\langle S \rangle$ would mean the set of finite products of elements of $S$, along with their *inverses*. I'm assuming this is what you meant. Anyway, wouldn't the continuous image of $[0, 1]$ be compact and therefore closed in $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: @mathmandan Yes that's what I meant - I edited the question accordingly. I agree that the continuous image of [0,1] is compact, and hence $S$ is closed in $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. Does this imply that $\langle S \rangle$ is closed as well?

Comment: You must be a bit more specific. Probably you want the topology to be the one induced by the inclusion in $SL(2,\Bbb C)$. Then the answer would be "no", because as is well known a torus contains dense non-closed (one-parameter) subgroups, which are not manifolds for the induced topology.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The only fact I care about is that the tangent space to the curves $s_t$ at the identity are in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $\langle S \rangle$, and hence $\text{exp}(\mathfrak{g}) \subset \langle S \rangle$ (and for this to make sense I need $\langle S \rangle$ to be a Lie group). I think this means I don't care about the topology of the induced group (but let me know if I'm missing something!).